# One-to-one correspondance between zeta zeros and the prime powers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

This question is highly speculative, but I would really appreciate some insight into the problem. Previously asked on MSE without answer [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339134/one-to-one-correspondance-between-zeta-zeros-and-the-prime-powers).

I have noticed an interesting property related to the Gibbs phenomenon for the Fourier transform of the zeta zeros in Riemann's explicit formula, namely that the rate at which $r\rightarrow 2 $ in the interval $[2,3]$

[image]

where $r_n$ is the $n$th solution to

$$\operatorname{li}(x)-\sum_{\rho_n}\operatorname{li}(x^{\rho_n})-\log 2+\int_{x}^{\infty}dt/(t(t^2-1)\log t)=1$$

for partial sums of $\sum_{\rho_n}\operatorname{li}(x^{\rho_n}), n\in \mathbb{N}$

From initial observations, it seems that for each sucessive zero added, $r_n-2\sim C/\operatorname{li}(n)$ for some $C<1/2.$

Much the same results can be achieved with finding $r_n$ for the partials sums at the points where

$$x-\sum_{\gamma_n}^{}\dfrac{2\log x\sin(\gamma_n \log x)}{\gamma_n\sqrt{x}} = 5/2$$

where $\gamma_n=$ imaginary parts of zeta zeros.

Does this suggest that the zeta zeros and the prime powers are in some sort of one to one correspondance?

Comment: Do you mean that $r$ is a value $x$ at which the first display holds? There is no $r$ in that equation, that's why I am asking. Similarly, there is no $r$ in your second equation. The question is unclear to me.

Comment: @GHfromMO yes, I have mixed $x$ & $n$ carelessly - the second display shouold read $x$ rather than $n$ to maintain consistency. Yes, I mean $r_n$ is a value at which the first display holds for the $n$th $\rho.$ Hope that is a bit clearer - if not, I will try to rephrase question.

Comment: What do you mean by "the first display holds for the $n$th $\rho$"? The first display involves a sum of $\rho$'s, not a single $\rho$. At any rate, please update the question with appropriate notation. Thanks!

Comment: @GHfromMO I hope that is a bit clearer now. If not, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it is still unfortunate to call $r_n$ the $n$-th solution $x$, while $n$ is the running variable for the zeros as well. That is, $r_n$ should be called $x_m$ and at appropriate (but not all) places $n$ should be called $m$ accordingly.

Comment: @GHfromMO I wansn't sure - would you advise me to update again, or shall I just leave it as is?

Comment: I think you should update a question as long as you can improve it. Updating is fun and useful.

Comment: @GHfromMO OK will do - didn't want to unnecessarily bump it to the top of the active questions though :) - will have to locate the file to recreate the image ...

Comment: Don't worry about bumps. Readers appreciate the effort put into a question.

Comment: This may have something interesting, but there is no clear question as it stands.  The explicit formula of course gives a correspondence between zeta zeros and primes, but it's not clear what exactly you're after here.

Comment: @Lucia I think I really need to have some time to think about it - how to phrase it properly, etc. Of course I know what I mean, but that certainly doesn't mean everyone else does, or that I am right in my assumptions. Is there a time limit on these sort of things, or can I come back to it at some point when I have it clearer in my own head, and request for it to be reopened? Is it better to do this sooner rather than later?

Comment: @martin: Take as much time as you need. -- Your question can be reopened once you make clear what you would like to know, no matter whether this is today or in a year. Once you edit your question, it enters the reopen votes review queue, and gets attention from people who might vote to reopen. You can vote to reopen as well (the threshold for own questions is 250 points). Closed questions are autodeleted only if they have score $\leq 0$ and fulfil some further conditions.

Comment: @StefanKohl ah great, that is good to know :) Thanks for replying and letting me know - I think I shall need some time just to reformulate my ideas!